# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't combine fixed host and multihost URL formats

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, cloud-sql-proxy

When Connecting Postgresql db using sqlalchemy and cloud-sql-proxy but getting this error and connection string we used is below given with create_engine.

"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_port}/{db_name}?host=cloud-sql-proxy"

Any modifications required in the connection string or any other way of connection method to get valid url.

Comment: Along with the string, can you please post the whole python command used for creating a connection. You may obfuscate the host name.